# Java: parameterizing Map object

Tags: java, polymorphism, parameterized

I have the following global variable:

```
private Map<String,List<String>> network;
```

I instantiate it in my constructor like this:

```
network = new Hashtable<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

The above instantiation does not compile. Apparently when I parametrize the Map, I must declare that it is a mapping specifically from String to ArrayList instead of using the more general List? Any insight as to why I must do this?

Comment: You should look into the Guava Multimap. Specifically, the ListMultimap implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, you can't subclass the internal class:

```
network = new Hashtable<String,List<String>>();
```

But when you add a member, you can create the value as an arraylist.

```
network.put("Key", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 3):

It's rather the reverse: when you create the new HashTable, you **don't** have to specify that you're going to be using ArrayLists as values. Instead, you should say

```
new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
```

and the choice of the List implementation(s) you are going to use as values remains free.

Answer (score 1):

You could also parameterise your variable as

```
private Map<String, ? extends List<String>> network;
```

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java for more details.